# STM32F407 Control de memoria RAM

Tags: embebido, arm, ram

Trabajo con el IDE IAR Workbench 8.22  y necesito controlar el uso de RAM en tiempo real. ¿Existe alguna funcion, macro de IAR que me permita ver el consumo de RAM en modod dinamico?.

El problema es que al de x tiempo de estar en ejecucion el programa, hago una actualizacion de un valor en un mapa y casca el programa, Tiene pinta de ser algo de memoria, por eso quiero controlarla.

Comment: No domino de tu tema pero no se si esta respuesta en este [foro](http://e2e.ti.com/support/microcontrollers/msp430/f/166/t/32627) te puede ayudar

Comment: Gracias pero no es eso. Esa respuesta lo que te da es la memoria usada al compilar el proyecto, pero no la que se usa mientras esta en ejecucion. El problema es que al de x tiempo de estar en ejecucion el programa, hago una actualizacion de un valor en un mapa y casca el programa, Tiene pinta de ser algo de memoria, por eso quiero controlarla.

Answer (score 0):

Bien, lo he solucionado sobrecargando los operadores new y delete.

https://www.iar.com/support/resources/articles/mastering-stack-and-heap-for-system-reliability/